# Concatenating JS files using apache ant concat for multiple folder structure

Tags: javascript, build, ant, concatenation

I have below folder structure

> build/common/js/app/
>
> build/theme-1/js/app/

Under app folder we have the JS files.
I wanted to concat the JS files and generate app.js for both the folder structure at a time. 
Below code doesn't seem to be working fine.

```
<fileset id="otherjsappfiles" dir="${jsSourceDir}">
    <include name="**/*.js"/>
    <exclude name="**/app.js"/>
</fileset>
<concat destfile="${jsSourceDir}/app.js" encoding="UTF-8" eol="lf" fixlastline="yes" outputencoding="UTF-8">
   <fileset refid="otherjsappfiles"/>
</concat>
```

The above code doesn't seem to work for common and theme-1.

I need to generate individual app.js for both common and theme-1 after concatenating respective JS files present inside these folders.

> build/common/js/app/app.js
>
> build/theme-1/js/app/app.js

Comment: What is the value of jsSourceDir? Are you running the above task just once?

Comment: jsSourceDir value is 'build', and Yes I am running it just once. I want optimized code which could do the job.

Comment: In case it helps: a concat task can only write one file.  What sort of optimisation are you after? Concat of a few js files shouldn't take long unless its done in an unusual way.

Comment: Is it recommended to write the same code as I posted in the question twice ?one for common/js and other for common/theme-1

Comment: When you say it "doesn't seem to work" what do you mean? Are you getting an error? Is the build completing successfully but there's no new file written to `build/app.js`? The file is written but it's missing content?

Comment: The file is not generating for both common and theme-1. It is successful. Still It didn't generate any files. I need two app.js (concatenated file) created for common and theme-1 inside their app folder respectively.

Comment: The `concat` task creates one file. You stated in an earlier comment that the value of `${jsSourceDir}` is "build", so the code you posted will create the new file in `build`, not `build/common` or `build/theme-1`. If you want to create two files, you will have to run this process twice and specify the correct `destfile` each time.